# In R, comparing 2 fields across 2 rows in a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, data-analysis, data-science, rscript

I am trying to compare 2 different fields across consecutive rows on a data frame in R and indicate the ones that are different. Below is the input data:-

```
 Start    End
1 Atl      Bos    
2 Bos      Har  
3 Har      NYC  
4 Stf      SFO
5 SFO      Chi
```

I am trying to establish a chain of movement and where the End doesn't match up to the Start of the next row I want to indicate that row. So for the above I would indicate row 4 as below:-

```
 Start    End    Ind
1 Atl      Bos   Y 
2 Bos      Har   Y
3 Har      NYC   Y
4 Stf      SFO   N
5 SFO      Chi   Y
```

I am pretty new to R, I have tried looking up this problem but cant seem to find a solution. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative would be:

```
> Ind <- as.character(dat$Start[-1]) == as.character(dat$End [-length(dat$End)])
> dat$Ind <- c(NA, ifelse(Ind==TRUE, "Y", "N")) 
> dat
  Start End  Ind
1   Atl Bos <NA>
2   Bos Har    Y
3   Har NYC    Y
4   Stf SFO    N
5   SFO Chi    Y
```

Note that your first item should be `<NA>`

Comment: They'd probably be better off either making both columns char or setting their factor levels to be the same, considering values in both cols belong to the same pool (rather than doing `as.character` on the fly for each such operation).

Comment: Thanks @Jilber that is exactly what I was looking for. Although if you don't mind a quick explanation. I am not quite clear on the **dat$End [-length(dat$End)])** part of the logic. I am not quite clear what its doing.

Comment: Thanks @Frank I will use the advice to make the code more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with `dplyr` using `mutate` and `lead`. Note that the last item should be `NA` because there is no line 6 to compare SFO-CHI to.

```
library(dplyr)
df1  <- read.table(text=" Start    End
Atl      Bos
Bos      Har
Har      NYC
Stf      SFO
SFO      Chi", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

df1 %>%
mutate(Ind=ifelse(End==lead(Start),"Y","N"))

  Start End  Ind
1   Atl Bos    Y
2   Bos Har    Y
3   Har NYC    N
4   Stf SFO    Y
5   SFO Chi <NA>
```

Comment: Thanks @P Lapointe. I see what you are doing there. The only thing is I need the 'N' indicator on the row where the Start doesn't match the previous row's End. The solution given by @Jilber above hits the nail on the head. But when using dplyr I can easily modify your code to fit my needs.

Comment: Yes, just change `lead` to `lag` and it should work the way you want.